# The Let's Encrypt cert doesn't work on Apache and FreeBSD

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

Our server administrator installed via Certbot the free Let's Encrypt certificate on our server with FreeBSD. But the cert doesn't work and we can't understand how exaclty we should configure the file `/usr/local/etc/apache24/httpd.conf` and/or `/usr/local/etc/apache24/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` ?

We use virtual hosts to host a few websites at the server. And the directory with websites is `/usr/local/www/apache24/`

Should we duplicate `<VirtualHost>` for the domain but with the port `:443`?

How in SSH to check whether the cert is working?

---

**EDIT**

I've just run the command `certbot --apache -d example.com`, but now if I open the website I get the 502 Bad Gateway error.

Here is our updated `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/www/apache24/public_html"
    SSLEngine on

   <Directory "/usr/local/www/apache24/public_html">
   Options -Indexes
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
      </Directory>
            SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem
Include /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I see that Apache stopped working. If I try to run `service apache24 start` I get the error

> Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address
> 0.0.0.0:443

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? How do you know that? SSH has nothing to do with that, you need to use web browser to see if the certificate appears on the site. (You can also use `openssl s_client` to check it and see the details, but not necessarily over SSH.)

Comment: HTTPS configuration is documented. If you have trouble with the configuration provide what you have configured and the exact error messages you encounter.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Please see my edit to the question

Comment: Your message means something is already running and bound to that address:port (likely, that is old or orphaned Apache httpd process). Try to kill it and restart a service. After that, please check Apache's *error log*, especially messages generated during startup.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov The admin said that the command `certbot --apache ...` I run replaced all the Apache config with its own, so all the websites stopped working

Comment: certbot creates  000-default-le-ssl.conf.  Was that where your apache config was stored?